# Beginning Haskell - composing function with data constructor and IO monad

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I have the following:

```
import Data.List

data Content
  = TaggedContent (String, [String]) String
  | Null

processContent :: Content -> IO Content
processContent c@(TaggedContent (id, attrs) text) =
  case stripPrefix "include=" a of
       Just f     -> return . TaggedContent (id, attrs) =<< readFile f
       Nothing    -> return c
  where a = head(attrs)
processContent x = return x

transformContent :: Content -> Content
transformContent x = x -- (details of implementation not necessary)
```

I would like to compose  `transformContent` with the `TaggedContent` constructor; that is, something like

```
       Just f     -> return . transformContent TaggedContent (id, attrs) =<< readFile f
```

However, this will not compile.

I am new to Haskell and am trying to understand the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need an extra dot:

```
return . transformContent . TaggedContent (id, attrs) =<< readFile f
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Wagner explained how to perform a minimal modification to get your code to compile. I will comment on a few common alternatives.

Code such as

```
return . g =<< someIOAction
```

is often also written as

```
fmap g someIOAction
```

or

```
g `fmap` someIOAction
```

or, after importing `Control.Applicative`

```
g <$> someIOAction
```

In your specific case, you could use:

```
transformContent . TaggedContent (id, attrs) <$> readFile f
```